# change of bases - matrix representation of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to solve a problem and got stuck. I suppose I made a stupid mistake somewhere, could somebody explain where?

> Let $B = \{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ be a basis of a vector space $V$, and let
>   $B' = \{v_1, v_1 + v_2, v_1 + v_2 + v_3\}$. Now define a linear map
>   $α : V → V$ by $α(v_1) = v_2 + v_3$, $α(v_2) = v_3 + v_1$ and $α(v_3)
> = v_1 + v_2$. Suppose, that $A$ is a matrix representation for linear transformation using basis $B$ and $A'$ using $B'$. Find $A'$

Now, I now that $A'=P^{-1}AP$, where $P$ is the identity matrix $I:V_{B'} → V_B$. Now I find that

$$A=
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix},~ P=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}, ~ P^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

In that case $$A'=\begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 2& 1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

However, if I try to represent $A'$, I get this: $$\begin{array} .\alpha(v_1) = v_2 + v_3 \\\alpha(v_1+v_2)=v_1+v_2+2v_3 \\ \alpha(v_1+v_2+v_3)=2v_1+2v_2+2v_3\end{array}$$
Thus $$A'=\begin{pmatrix} 
-1 & 0& 1 \\
0 & -1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 2 
\end{pmatrix}$$

I suppose my 'direct' approach is wrong. Whats the correct way then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basis change matrix is
$$P=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0& 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: could you briefly explain why? I get $I(v_1)=v_1$,$I(v_1+v_2)=v_1+v_2$ and $I(v_1+v_2+v_3)=v_1+v_2+v_3$. How do you get an upper triangular matrix?

Comment: The first coulmn of $P$ is $(1,0,0)^T$ means $I(v_1)=1v_1+0v_2+0v_3$ and the same  for the second and third coulmn